# html form 2 fields unique values required

Tags: php

I have a html form which has around 10 fields. 2 of those fields must have unique values.

So if I've got:

- Name
- Date of Birth
- Email Address
- Current City
- Phone Number
- Favourite City << Must be unique compared to City Born
- City Born << Must be unique compared to Favourite City
- Favourite Colour
- Favourite Flower
- Favourite Animal

I've found the below for validation, but that applies to all form fields. I just need to apply the 'unique' requirement to these two fields...it'd be okay for 'Favourite City' and 'Current City' to have the same values.

Thanks.

```
var frm = document.querySelector('form.classesName');
var inputs = frm.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

frm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var classArr = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(classArr.indexOf(inputs[i].value) != -1) {
            inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            return false;
        }
        else
            classArr.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
    frm.submit();
});

for(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
    inputs[j].addEventListener('focus', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/70nkhthc/

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the JavaScript you posted, and making some assumptions regarding the HTML make up of your form, would something like this work out?

```js
var frm = document.querySelector('form.classesName');

frm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var favoriteCity = document.querySelector('input[name="favoriteCity"]');
    var cityBorn = document.querySelector('input[name="cityBorn"]');
    
    if ( favoriteCity.value === cityBorn.value ) {
      alert("The City Where One Was Born Can't Be Their Favorite City... ?");
      return false;
    }

    frm.submit();
});
```

```html
<form class='classesName'>
  <input type='text' name='favoriteCity' placeholder='Favorite City'>
  <input type='text' name='cityBorn' placeholder='City Born'>

  <input type='submit' value'Submit Form'>
</form>
```